# How to allow viewers to download a file through Google Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

There is a setting in Google Drive file sharing called 'Viewers and commenters can see the option to download, print, and copy'. It is false by default. I would like to enable it for some files programmatically so viewers could download them. I already have a service that changes permissions for files on Google Drive, but I don't see any API that corresponds to this setting: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use copyRequiresWriterPermission:

The option `Viewers and commenters can see the option to download, print, and copy` corresponds in the API to the following field from [File](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files):

> [copyRequiresWriterPermission](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#copyRequiresWriterPermission)

Call [Files: update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update) and specify this property in the request body in order to modify this:

```
{
  "copyRequiresWriterPermission": true
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helped a lot, this is the required setting. But it should be set to `false` - because `copyRequiresWriterPermission` means that viewers can't download/copy (since they don't have writer permission) and I want them to be able to do it. I set it to `false` and everything works.