# Download a file through Google Drive API with the viewer/editor permission

Tags: google-api, download, google-drive-api

My workflow consists of:

1. A user shares a drive folder with me (from the GUI, with no dev experience)
2. I want to download files in this folder with the Google Drive API.

Currently, if the user shares his folder with the `editor` permission I can download the file with the [files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/get?hl=fr) method. But if he shares the folder with the `viewer` permission. I get `insufficientFilePermissions: The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.`

I saw in another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67617737/how-to-allow-viewers-to-download-a-file-through-google-drive-api) that you can update the [copyRequiresWriterPermission](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files?hl=fr#copyRequiresWriterPermission). But this needs to be done by API if I understand correctly. (Which is impossible for my users since they are not technical)

So is there an easy solution to make it work with the `viewer` permission or should I stick with the `editor` solution? If so, is there documentation that proves to my users that I have no choice but to use the `editor` solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is still possible to download files if you have the viewer permission, however the `copyRequiresWriterPermission` permission has to be changed. This can be done through the Drive UI as well, the API is not necessary to do this change.

It is important to note that this **permission applies to the file**, not the folder, so if the user shares the folder with you with the viewer permission, they will still need to change the `copyRequiresWriterPermission` for you to be able to download files. Rather than using the API, the user can use the Google Drive UI to select multiple files within the folder, then enable the permission.

1. Within the folder, select multiple files at once, click on `Share`, go to `Settings`.

[image: sampleFiles]

2. Check the box `Viewers and commenters can see the option to download, print, and copy`, this way you will be able to download files with the `viewer` permission.

[image]

**Note:** If there is a `-` sign in that permission, uncheck the box and check again to apply to all selected files.
[image]

Of course, the easiest way would be to give you the `editor` permission, but that depends on how users share their files.

##### References:

- [Limit how your files are shared](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494893?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Cprevent-people-from-downloading-printing-or-copying-your-file:%7E:text=Limit%20how%20your%20files%20are%20shared)

Comment: Thanks I think it will be enough to convince my customers to give me the `editor` access.

Answer (score 0):

> insufficientFilePermissions: The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.

Means exactly that the currently authenticated user does not have permissions to do what you are trying to do.   You cant preform an access you dont have access to do.

Comment: I fully understand that. My question is more, how do I convince my (non technical) customers that I need to have the "editor" access then.

Comment: Just tell t hem if they want to use your app then you need edit access if they dont give it to you then they cant use your app its simple.